# What parameters can Java setAlignment Function have?

Tags: java

What are the parameters that can be passed in setAlignment Function. Also what does this `button1.setAlignment(1f)` mean .

For Example

```
public class TwoButtons extends JFrame {

    public TwoButtons() {

        setTitle("Two Buttons");

        JPanel basic = new JPanel();
        basic.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basic, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(basic);

        basic.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setAlignmentX(1f);
        bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        JButton close = new JButton("Close");

        bottom.add(ok);
        bottom.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
        bottom.add(close);
        bottom.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 0)));

        basic.add(bottom);
        basic.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 15)));

        setSize(300, 250);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: also please tell me what that Box.createRigidArea does

Comment: updated my answer for info about Box.createRigidArea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are talking about setAlignmentX(1f) method. This method is defined in JComponent class. It sets the the vertical alignment.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX(float)

```
Possible values for setAlignmentX are 

Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT  0.5f
Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT    0.0f
Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT   1.0f
```

In your case it is **"1f"** so this component has **(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT) Right vertical alignment**

[Box.createRigidArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createRigidArea(java.awt.Dimension))
Creates an invisible component that's always the specified size.

Answer (score -1):

All methods in Java belong to a class, and as it is (without the class name) I have no idea which method you're talking about.

If you *do* know the class name, and it's a core Java class, then check out the [official API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/) for a list of all of the classes and methods involved in the J2SE API.  Just find the class you're interested in on the left hand side, click on it and you'll see a list of all its methods, together with documentation and parameter lists.

If it's not a core Java class then you'll need to find the API for the library that defines it.  Almost all commonly-downloadable libraries will have an "API" or "Javadocs" link on their homepage that you can follow to achieve the same thing as above.

And if you *don't* know the class name, that's the first thing to find out.  (Without it your question is like asking "Who lives at house number 34?"  You'll need the street name and quite possibly town name to get an answer without the specific context.)

Comment: sorry Andrzej but everything went above my head. Cant clearly understand what u trying to say

Comment: Follow the link in my post.  This is the documentation for all of the classes that are included in Java.  You will find the class in question there (which I can now see is JPanel), and can see all of the methods declared on that class along with their documentation.